# Getting Script Name from wscript.exe Process

Tags: vbscript

I am using this code:

```
Dim name
name = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%computername%")
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _ 
    & name & "\root\cimv2")
For Each hwnd In wmi.InstancesOf("Win32_Process")
    If hwnd.Name = "wscript.exe" Then
        'get name and possibly location of currently running script
    End If
Next
```

I am successfully listing all processes and picking out the `wscript.exe`. However, I have searched and have found no way to find the name of the script running in `wscript.exe`, ie. is it `myscript.vbs` or `jscript.js` or anything. Bonus if there is a way to find the whole path of the script.

**EDIT:**

With more searching, I found a solution. In the above script, the `hwnd` variable stores the handle for the `wscript.exe` process. There is a property for handles: `hwnd.CommandLine`. It shows how to call it from the command line, so it would be something like:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe" "C:\path\to\script.vbs"
```

So I can parse the `hwnd.CommandLine` string to find the path and name of all running scripts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have `ScriptName` and `ScriptFullName` properties.

```
' in VBScript
WScript.Echo WScript.ScriptName
WScript.Echo WScript.ScriptFullName

// in JScript
WScript.Echo(WScript.ScriptName);
WScript.Echo(WScript.ScriptFullName);
```

[EDIT] Here you go (use `.CommandLine` property):

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
    & "." & "\root\cimv2")

Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery( _
    "Select * from Win32_Process " _
    & "Where Name = 'WScript.exe'", , 48)

Dim strReport
For Each objProcess in colProcesses
    ' skip current script, and display the rest
    If InStr (objProcess.CommandLine, WScript.ScriptName) = 0 Then
        strReport = strReport & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            "ProcessId: " & objProcess.ProcessId & vbNewLine & _
            "ParentProcessId: " & objProcess.ParentProcessId & _
            vbNewLine & "CommandLine: " & objProcess.CommandLine & _
            vbNewLine & "Caption: " & objProcess.Caption & _
            vbNewLine & "ExecutablePath: " & objProcess.ExecutablePath
    End If
Next
WScript.Echo strReport
```

Comment: Perhaps my question is confusing. I know how to get the name of thecurrently running vbscript. I was asking how to get the name of a running script from the handle of another wscript.exe.

Comment: Aha, my bad then, now I see what you ask for. Ok, I'll edit my answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
myProcess="wscript.exe"               
Set Processes = GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf("Win32_Process")
For Each Process In Processes
 If StrComp(Process.Name, myProcess, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then     'check if process exist      
   CmdLine=process.commandline                  
 End If
Next
myArr=split(CmdLine,"\")
mySN=replace(myArr(ubound(myArr)),"""","")
Wscript.Echo "Full Pth: " & Cmdline &vbcrlf&"Script Name: "& mySN
```